# how to convert normal image to a template image to be used for a button

Tags: ios, swift

Creating Green Photo

```
for y in 0..<myRGBA!.height {
    for x in 0..<myRGBA!.width {
        let index = y * (myRGBA?.width)! + x
        var pixel = myRGBA?.pixels[index]
        let greenDif = Int((pixel?.green)!) - avrGreen

        if greenDif > 0 {
            pixel?.green = UInt8(max(0, min(255, avrGreen + greenDif*5)))
            myRGBA?.pixels[index] = pixel!
        }
    }
}

greenImage = myRGBA?.toUIImage()

let greenTemplate = UIImage(named: "greenImage")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

green.setImage(greenTemplate, forState: .Normal)
```

I'm working on image processing application and I want to use the processed image as a template image for filter buttons icons (same as Instagram filters)

I'm using the code:

```
UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

"YourImageName" means the source image or the output image? if it's the source image, should I get the output in the same property?

however it didn't work. When I simulate the app still the names of the filters buttons appear instead of the image as I want.

Comment: Please put the actual code in your question instead of as an image. It makes it much easier to read and much easier to reference when providing answers.

Comment: I did..have a look please..much appreciated